# how to pass data to ajax for an express api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax, express

I'm developing a website with express and ejs. I got into a trouble where i need to call an api via ajax. The problem is on a button onclick i'm passing two values to ajax data. but it gives error ,i tried a lot of ways and i'm messed up. i'm a newbie , find my code below.

```
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'));
    
   
    const container = document.getElementById('s1');
 
    parsedData.data.rows.forEach((result, idx) => {
      
     var a = result.master_id;
     var b = result.session_name;
     console.log(a,b,"a","b")
     
   
    var userData = {"pid":a,"session" :b};
     console.log(userData,"userData");
    sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(userData));
    console.log(userData,"data for api");

     const card = document.createElement('div');
     card.classList = 'card';

  
  const content = `
  <div class="row">
      <div class="card-body"  onclick="graphApi()">
  </div>
  </div>


  `;


  container.innerHTML += content;
});

function graphApi(){
       
      var apiValue =JSON.parse( sessionStorage.getItem("user"));
       console.log(apiValue, "value from card");
       

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:  apiValue,
        dataType:"json",
        
        url: "http://localhost:5000/graphFromcsv",                      
        success: function(data) {
        console.log(data,"graph api");
}
  error: function(err){
          alert("graph api failed to load");
          console.log(err);
        },
});
```

i'm always getting this pid in api value undefined and 400 badrequest . but if i use raw data like,

```
{
    "pid":"WE6",
    "session":"W.csv"
}
```

instead of apiValue my ajax is success and i'm gettig the data. i'm using this data to plot a multiple line graph. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove dataType:json

Comment: i tried that but didn't helped

Comment: Do you mean `data: apiValue` instead of `data: { apiValue }`?

Comment: data: apiValue . i wrote it incorrect in this question sorry. but not in my code

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct `data` key and their value(value must be string in case of json data)  and also add `contentType` key like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: sessionStorage.getItem("user") || '{}',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/graphFromcsv",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data, "graph api");
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("graph api failed to load");
        console.log(err);
    },
});
```

**Note:** In backend(`ExpressJS`), make sure you are using correct `body-parser` middleware like `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: thanks. but this didn't worked,sorry. still getting error bad request

Comment: @fungusblacky updated answer, I  missed line `var apiValue =JSON.parse( sessionStorage.getItem("user"));`  You do not need to parse it, it should be  like `var apiValue = sessionStorage.getItem("user");` if you want to use `apiValue` variable in `data` key

Comment: i tried this too brother. I got this error in browser console {message: 'TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object'}. and when i use alret (err) instead of alert('graph api failed to load') i got  [object Object]

Comment: @fungusblacky seems like you are not sending any data from backend, you just need to remove `dataType: "json",`

Comment: i did the same still nothing bro. and do i have to change res.json({ data}) to res.send({data}) in backend api

Comment: when i removed the  dataTpye: "json",  i got this error {message: 'TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object'}

Comment: any more inputs? bro

Answer (score 0):

Let assume your `apiValue` contain `{"pid":"WE6", "session":"W.csv" }` then `body: { apiValue }` will be equal to:

```js
  body: {
    apiValue: {
      "pid":"WE6",
      "session":"W.csv"
    }
  }
```

But if you use the link to the object like `body: apiValue` (without brackets) js will build it like:

```js
body: {
  "pid":"WE6",
  "session":"W.csv"
}
```

Comment: sorry i didn't get it, should i add apivalue?

Comment: Can you provide what you get from `console.log(apiValue, "value from card");` ?

Comment: {"pid":"W6","session":"W.csv"} value from card  when i use   var apiValue = sessionStorage.getItem("user");
       console.log(apiValue, "value from card");

Comment: And the data that works is `{"pid":"WE6", "session":"W.csv"}`. Can it be that you missing `E` in `W6`?

Comment: yes bro typing mistake