# how to make json key value pair using two var

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax

I have two var's

```
var a = result.master_id;
var b = result.session_name;
```

i want to create a json string to pass to ajax. i tried this

```
var userData = {'pid':a,'session' :b};
```

i'm storing this userData in a sessionStorage and sending to ajax . but i'm getting pid undefined error.

is this the right way to do this?

any help is appreciated.
regards,
newbie

Comment: `but i'm getting pid undefined error` please show the exact error that you get, and where you get that error. Nothing of the shown code will directly emit such an error. With the given information it is hard to tell where the error occurs and why it might be that case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69550477/how-to-pass-data-to-ajax-for-an-express-api-call?noredirect=1#comment122933411_69550477  please have a look at this question .

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. (Where does there error occur, client-side or server-side and at what particular part of the code)? And furthermore, how is your question then different from your previously asked one?

Comment: error is happening client side in chrome. the previous question was the base for this one cause i was passing this kinda data to ajax . but was giving the same error. so o thought maybe the json string is not correct. that's why i asked this one.

Comment: Please show a copy and past of the actual error message (including the stacktrace). Nothing in the shown code (neither this question nor the linked one) would produce an error that would say that `pid` is undefined. So it is essential to know the exact error message with the information in which file the error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the right code to store into variable. Try to console variable to identify.

Example code given below:

```
let result = {
master_id: 1,
session_name: "Hardik"
}

var a = result.master_id;
var b = result.session_name;

var userData = {'pid':a,'session' :b};

console.log(userData);
```

Comment: ok bro but when store this userData and while sending it to ajax it gives error. ajax was unsuccessfull

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69550477/how-to-pass-data-to-ajax-for-an-express-api-call?noredirect=1#comment122933411_69550477 please check this question.